# Округление до заданного числа PHP

Tags: php

Мне необходимо округлять числа до заданных вручную, например:

```
131 -> 0
385 -> 500
831 -> 1000
749 -> 500
```

Каким образом можно такое сделать?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть весь текст задачи. В текущем виде она просто не понятна. Как можно 131 "округлить" до 0? Опишите задачу полностью.

Comment: поделить на 1000, применить round, умножить на 1000

Comment: @Алексей - ну какое же это "округление"? :) Это целый алгоритм как из одного числа получить другое. Поэтому я и прошу весь текст задачи, там же наверняка написано используя какие функции `php` или математические методы нужно получить из одного числа другое.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если 749 поделить на тысячу и округлить то получим 0. Задача не про округление, а на поиск ближайшей точки из заданных, с шагом 500, вероятно.

Comment: поясните, 0 500 1000 это просто фиксированные значения, или это ряд чисел с шагом 500 ?

Comment: @teran вообще-то в зависимости от precision будет либо 1, либо 0,7)) но да, я чуть ошибся)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, на 500 делить надо. если речь, конечно, не о трёх фиксированных значениях (0, 500, 1000).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да я знаю) На первый взгляд показалось то, что показалось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для фиксированного числа точек, что-то такое будет

```
$points = [0,500,1000];    
$data   = [131,385,831,749];

$finder = function($v) use ($points) {
            $min = PHP_INT_MAX;
            $res = null;
            
            foreach($points as $idx => $p){
                if($min > abs($p - $v)){
                    $min = abs($p-$v);
                    $res = $p;
                }
            }
            return $res;
                
          };


foreach($data as $v){
    echo "$v - {$finder($v)}\n";
}
```